# matplotlib barplot not working with logarithmic scale

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to do a barplot in Matplotlib in logarithmic scale. If I do this manually (figure 3 below) I get the correct answer, but if I use matplotlib's `set_yscale('log')` or use the log attribute of the barplot, I get the wrong plot. So as you can see in figs 1 and 2, the plot is wrong, since log10(y2) = ([ 5.7363965 ,  5.77815125])

Below is a MWE:

```
from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

ind = np.array(['US', 'EU'])
y2 = [545000, 600000]

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.bar(ind, y2)
ax.set_yscale('log')
plt.title('example 1')
#plt.savefig('../../Desktop/ex1.jpg')

fig = plt.figure(2)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.bar(ind, y2, log=True)
plt.title('example2')
#plt.savefig('../../Desktop/ex2.jpg')


fig2 = plt.figure(3)
ax1 = fig2.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.bar(ind, np.log10(y2))
plt.title('example 3')
#plt.savefig('../../Desktop/ex3.jpg')
plt.show()
```

and here are the figures:
[image: Figure1]

[image: Figure2]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at your y axis limits in the first figure using `print(plt.gca().get_ylim())`, I get:

```
(542386.3669524404, 602891.2596703834)
```

Therefore, only 1 major tick will be visible in log scale as is the case in figures 1 and 2 in the question. To get a similar graph to your 3rd one, you need to set the limits of your y axis:

```
ind = np.array(['US', 'EU'])
y2 = [545000, 600000]

fig = plt.figure(1)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
plt.bar(ind, y2)
plt.ylim(1,1000000)  # set y axis limits
ax.set_yscale('log')
plt.title('example 1')

plt.show()
```

[image]